# Bash redirection: save stderr/stdout to different files and still print them out on a console

Tags: bash

Here is a simple program.

```
class Redirection {

public static void main (String args[]){
    System.out.println("Hello World_Stdout");
    System.err.println("Hello World_Stderr");
}

}
```

I want to see the all the outputs on a console, but at the same time I want to store stdout and stderr in different files. I tried the following command, to no avail.

```
$java Redirection 3>&1 2>stderr 1>stdout 1>&3 2>&3
```

stderr& stdout files have the file size of 0.

So basically I want to do what "tee" command does but I also want to capture stderr as well.

Comment: As an aside -- as a consequence of file semantics on UNIX, if the two file descriptors don't have the same immediate destination, there's no guarantee that writes will complete in order; thus, if you did one write to each of stderr or stdout very near the other, it's possible for the lines to have their order flipped when they're going through separate pipelines.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is an answer:

`./yourScript.sh   > >(tee stdout.log) 2> >(tee stderr.log >&2)`

If your script has STDOUT and STDERR descriptors, you get 2 files *stdout.log* + *stderr.log* and all output (Err + Out) to console.

Comment: what if you want to capture both stderr and stdout to different files and still see both on a console?

Comment: **./your.sh 2>&1 | tee -a log**
This  redirects stderr to stdout, so tee echoes both to log and to screen.    It should work too

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I want to save 1) stderr and stdout to separate files and 2) see both of them on console.

Comment: well, I paste here above typed command:                         `./myscript 3>&1 1>stdout.logfile 2>&3- | tee -a stderr.logfile`         where `stdout.logfile` is one file and `stderr.logfile` is second one. For console we put STDOUT and STDERR together

Comment: that command you typed correctly produced two files, but it only displayed stderr on a console :(  
$ java Redirection 3>&1 1>stdout.logfile 2>&3- | tee -a stderr.logfile
Hello World_Stderr

Comment: Please, take a look on new changes i did to previous answer, i checked, it works. Enjoy.

Comment: Thank you. It works!! but there is one minor flaw that is, there is no line feed between stdout and stderr on a console. Is there way to fix this? Right now it looks like:
java Redirection > >(tee stdout.log) 2> >(tee stderr.log >&2)
Hello World_StdoutHello World_Stderr(that is no line break betweent HelloWorld_Std and Hello WOrld_Stderr

Comment: I used bash script and it seems good. If you run `java Redirection` only, does it print on 2 lines?

Comment: @MaximShoustin curious - how does bash implementation of java program here would look like?