# bash exec sending output to a pipe, how?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I experiment with exec'ing the bash itself only to redirect the output. If I use redirection like

```
exec >bla.log
ls
exec 1>&2
```

it works as expected: the `ls` output ends up in `bla.log` and after the second `exec` things are back to normal, mainly because handle 2 is still bound to the terminal.

Now I thought to send the output through a pipe instead of into a file, a trivial example being `exec | cat >bla.log`. However, the command immediately returns. To figure out what is going on, I did this:

```
exec | bash -c 'echo $$; ls -l /proc/$$/fd /proc/23084/fd'
```

where 23084 is the bash currently running and got this:

```
24002
/proc/23084/fd:
total 0
lrwx------ 1 harald harald 64 Aug 14 20:17 0 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 harald harald 64 Aug 14 20:17 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 harald harald 64 Aug 14 20:17 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 harald harald 64 Aug 14 20:17 255 -> /dev/pts/1

/proc/24002/fd:
total 0
lr-x------ 1 harald harald 64 Aug 14 21:56 0 -> pipe:[58814]
lrwx------ 1 harald harald 64 Aug 14 21:56 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 harald harald 64 Aug 14 21:56 2 -> /dev/pts/1
```

As we can see, the sub-process 24002 is indeed listening to a pipe. But it certainly is not the parent process, 23084, which has this pipe open.

Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: [Possible workaround](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-redirections-using-exec)

Comment: `exec 1>&2` is not exactly "back to normal" -- that directs stdout to stderr. Back to normal would be something like `exec 3>&1; exec 1>blah.log; ls; exec 1>&3; exec 3>&-`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When a command contains a pipeline, each subcommand is run in a subshell. So the shell first forks a subshell for each part of the pipeline, and then the subshell for the first part executes `exec` with no arguments, which does nothing and exits.

`exec` with redirection and no command is treated as a special case. From the documentation:

> If command is not specified, any redirections take effect in the
>                 current shell, and the return status is 0.

Answer (score 27):

#### What

The proper way to implement something that might otherwise be written

```
exec | cat >bla.log
```

is

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^ - IMPORTANT: not /bin/sh

exec > >(cat >bla.log)
```

---

#### Why

This is because `>()` is a [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst); it's replaced with a filename (of the `/dev/fd/NN` form if possible, or a temporary FIFO otherwise) which, when written to, will deliver to the stdin of the enclosed process. (`<()` is similar, but in the other direction: being substituted with the name of a file-like object which will, when read, return the given process's stdout).

Thus, `exec > >(cat >bla.log)` is roughly equivalent to the following (on an operating system that doesn't provide `/dev/fd`, `/proc/self/fds`, or similar):

```
mkfifo "tempfifo.$$"           # implicit: FIFO creation
cat >bla.log <"tempfifo.$$" &  # ...start the desired process within it...
exec >"tempfifo.$$"            # explicit: redirect to the FIFO
rm "tempfifo.$$"               # ...and can unlink it immediately.
```

Comment: Can somebody explain, please?

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak, amended.

Comment: Very helpful. A more instructive usecase would be to use the `ts` utility to timestamp all output.

Comment: I think this is the way to do and should bee marked as a solution, the other one is just explanation why it doesn't work.

Comment: I've ended up doing something like this:
```
#!/bin/bash

exec > >(logger -t bashtest) 2>&1

ls -l

ls -lqwe12
```

Answer (score 5):

It took me a while to figure out how to get the combination of redirections right for stdout and stderr, so this might be useful to others.

The following examples illustrate using redirections with tee as a "pipe" target while distinguishing stdout and stderr.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "stdout"
echo "stderr" >&2

echo "stdout to out.log" | tee out.log
echo "stderr to err.log" 2>&1 >&2 | tee err.log >&2

exec 2> >(tee -a err.log >&2)
exec > >(tee -a out.log)

echo "exec stdout to out.log"
echo "exec stderr to err.log" >&2
```

Run this in the CLI with stdout redirected to /dev/null and you only see the stderr messages.  Plus within each log file you only see the relevant messages.

Note that the order of the `exec 2>` line and the `exec >` lines is important.  Essentially we first want to redirect stderr to an error file, then stdout to a log file.  If these lines appear in the opposite order the results would not be correct.

Comment: You can use just one `exec` with multiple redirections, btw; they'll be performed in left-to-right order. So `exec 2> >(tee -a err.log >&2) > >(tee -a out.log)` works as a single command.

Comment: (BTW, this is *definitely* a useful answer and a helpful contribution to the site, but I'm not sure that this question is the right place for it -- the OP here isn't asking how to copy stdout and stderr to separate files, but how to direct them to the same destination; this looks more like a hybrid of the current question with [Bash redirection: save stdout/stderr to different files and still print them out on a console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927927/bash-redirection-save-stderr-stdout-to-different-files-and-still-print-them-out)).